# basic question about work exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work

I am learning independently from Tobochnik's statistical physics text.

He asks a warm up question about work:

> A person pushes a block up a frictionless ramp.  Is the work positive, negative, or zero in the following: (a) The work done by the person's hand on the block. (b) The work done by the block on the person. (c) The work done by gravity on the block.

Are the following answers correct?  I try to give some justification. 
(a) positive (b) negative (c) negative

There are three forces acting on the block: the hand, gravity, and the normal force.  The force of gravity equals the normal force, so the net force on the block equals the force of the hand.  In (a), the work done by the hand is positive since the direction of motion is the same as the direction of the force.  In (b), the work done by gravity on the block is negative because the direction of motion is opposite the direction of the force.  The block exerts a force on the hand that is smaller in magnitude than the force of the hand on the block (otherwise the block would not move).  Therefore, in (c) the block does negative work on the hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are correct, the justification has some major problems.

1. You have a ramp, so the slope is not 0. That means that the normal force (which is perpendicular to the ramp) and the gravity (vertical) are not collinear, so they cannot cancel each other. In a reference frame with an axis parallel to the ramp, the gravity has a component perpendicular to the ramp, equal to the normal force (the block is not sinking into the ramp, nor does it start to float above it), but also has a component along the ramp (down slope). In the absence of friction, the force from the hand has to be at least equal to this parallel component. If they are equal, the block is either at rest, or moving with a constant velocity. It can move up or down. Or if the force is greater it will accelerate up the ramp.
2. For (a) the justification is correct.
3. For (b) there is a caveat, the gravity has two components. The component perpendicular to the plane does no work, the component parallel to the plane points down the ramp, the motion is up the ramp, so the work is negative
4. For (c) the force that the block is acting on the hand is equal in magnitude, and opposite in direction to the force the hand is acting on the block. This is Newton's 3rd law. **Very important note:** they are equal and act on **different** objects. So the work is negative, but equal in magnitude to the work at point (a)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.  One follow up question regarding point 4:  So I could correctly say that the force of gravity (parallel direction) + the block + the 'wrist' on the hand equals the net force of the hand on the block (since the relative motion of the hand with respect to the block is zero)?

Comment: No, since you don't know if it's moving at constant velocity. The block and the hand might both be accelerating

Comment: Did my last comment not account for the case they are both accelerating?  What I meant to say is that since we know the block and hand have the same acceleration (possibly zero) then we know their respective F/m's are the same, and above I was just trying to account for all the 'actors'.  But yea, I definitely said something totally incorrect in my last comment.